# Google Chrome frame + IE8 = Displays old data in a databound control till I refresh the page

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome-frame

Exactly as the title says. I am using a listView which is not being updated with new rows when I normally brows to the page by means of my navigation link. It only updates the list with new data when I refresh the browser.

Only happens on my IE 8 + chrome frame installation. Suggestions on how to elegantly(guess not available) handle this issue without going for hacks and stuff will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE has a bad habit of caching things it shouldn't, which may be causing your issue. Try adding some [no-cache headers](http://www.crydust.be/blog/2009/03/20/ie8-aggressive-caching-fix/) to your page and see if you still see the problem.